How to create a flamegraph on MacOS for C program?
After spending a few night writing some software I want to get a flamegraph for it in order to optimize my code.
In the past, I have used Linux which has perf and stackcollapse-perf.pl which do not work with MacOS. I tried to extract data from Instruments but did not succeed in creating a flamegraph from it.
How does one create flamegraphs on a Mac?

I ended up using sample.
